# Гем (RoR) для организации обмена c 1C

Tags: ruby-on-rails, 1с, spree

Существует ли гем для обмена заказами с 1С и магазина на Spree ('~> 3.0.9')? Возможно есть отлаженный и работающий форк уже устаревших гемов, он тоже может подойти.

Comment: Единственный актуальный гем, связанный с 1С это `s41c` и он явно не про это. Так что, видимо, нет.

Comment: не, не единственный точно, если пошарить по гитхабу, то можно понаходить, но старовато, например https://github.com/2rba/spree_xchange

Comment: **актуальных**, если измерять по RubyGems, больше нет вообще.

Comment: вполне возможно, что кто-то форкнул и довел до актуального состояния один из "несвежих" гемов, но вот что-то на глаза не попадаются, в интернетах видел форк Spree - 1R с якобы работающим обменом, но вот исходников никто не выкладывает, потому как судя по всему проект коммерческий.

Comment: D-side, и, кстати, за s41c отдельное спасибо, это тоже весьма пригодится!

Comment: Вопросы опросники запрещены в сообществе. Для повторного открытия, перефразируйте ваш вопрос так, чтобы на него можно было дать однозначно правильный ответ.

Comment: Лучше не стало, нет. Это по-прежнему опросник.

Comment: может я конечно не догоняю, но как нужно поставить вопрос, чтобы выяснить есть ли нужный мне гем или нет?

Comment: Вопросы с подобными ответами тут неуместны. Так что тут -- никак.